# How Do I separate Prints In Python?

Tags: python, web

So I have this code that I use to web crawl ebay just for educational purposes and it works great.

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_trksid=p2050601.m570.l1313.TR12.TRC2.A0.H0.Xps4.TRS0&_nkw=ps4&_sacat=0"

site = urllib.request.urlopen(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(site.read(), "html.parser")

listings =soup.find_all('a',class_='vip')

for listing in listings:

    print (listing['href']+","+ str(listing.string))
```

Now when I print it out I get [this](https://gyazo.com/e3179f457f47340f9eeec54af12e8732).

Is there possibly a way to add a space between each listing? Anyway thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming this is Python 3, so you can use the `end` parameter:

```
# end='\n' won't do anything since '\n' is already the default value for end
print(listing['href']+","+ str(listing.string), end='\n\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

I would simply do

```
for listing in listings:
    print(listing['href']+","+ str(listing.string))
    print("\n")
```

or just

```
for listing in listings:
    print(listing['href']+","+ str(listing.string)) + "\n"
```

The "\n" is a newline character.

Comment: Any reason to prefer this over `end='\n\n'`? (given that this is indeed Python 3)

Comment: @DeepSpace: Compatibility with Python 2 `print` statement + less typing for the same effect.